# Using EON charts in a Ember Page

Tags: pubnub

We are trying to use (pubnub) EON charts in an Ember application.

While we see [this](https://github.com/pubnub/pubnub-ember) which talks about using pubnub APIs in Ember, this doesn't talk about EON charts.

Is there a "Ember wrapped" EON chart variant? Either way some sample code will be helpful.

Comment: PubNub EON is just standard JS that wraps PubNub and D3 or Mapbox. No Ember specific implementations. I will have Ian, the EON creator, review this for more detailed advice/answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use EON with Ember just like any other library. Check out [this example](http://codepen.io/ianjennings/pen/EVvorY) which combines the [EON real time spline chart example](http://www.pubnub.com/developers/eon/chart/spline/) and the [ember starter kit](https://github.com/emberjs/starter-kit).

Your HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//pubnub.github.io/eon/v/eon/0.0.9/eon.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//pubnub.github.io/eon/v/eon/0.0.9/eon.css"/>
<div id="chart"></div>

<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

  {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
  <ul>
  {{#each item in model}}
    <li>{{item}}</li>
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

And then in your JS:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
  }
});

var pubnub = PUBNUB.init({
  publish_key: 'demo',
  subscribe_key: 'demo'
});
var channel = "c3-spline" + Math.random();
eon.chart({
  channel: channel,
  history: true,
  flow: true,
  pubnub: pubnub,
  generate: {
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
      labels: false
    }
  }
});

var pubnub = PUBNUB.init({
  publish_key: 'demo',
  subscribe_key: 'demo'
});
setInterval(function(){

  pubnub.publish({
    channel: channel,
    message: {
      eon: {
        'Austin': Math.floor(Math.random() * 99),
        'New York': Math.floor(Math.random() * 99),
        'San Francisco': Math.floor(Math.random() * 99),
        'Portland': Math.floor(Math.random() * 99)
      }
    }
  });

}, 1000);
```